# "Inconsistent datatypes: expected DATE got NUMBER" with DepartmentsImpl class

Tags: java, oracle11g, oracle-adf

I generate this class in the entity object departments and I create log table called departments_log(department_id number, entry_user number,
entry_date date) when the method try to enter the deleted record into this table this error appears:

> (inconsistent datatypes: expected DATE got NUMBER)

This is the do_dml method code :

```
if (operation == DML_DELETE) {
        FacesContext context = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
        UserInfo user =
            (UserInfo)context.getExternalContext().getSessionMap().get("userInfo");
        Number deptID = new Number(getDepartmentId());
        Date entryDate = new Date(Date.getCurrentDate());
        Number entryUser = new Number(user.getEmployeeId());
        String sql =
            "insert into departments_log (DEPARTMENT_ID,entry_user,entry_date) values (" +
            deptID + "," + entryUser + "," +
            entryDate + ")";
        PreparedStatement stm =
            getDBTransaction().createPreparedStatement(sql, 1);
        try {
            stm.executeUpdate(sql);
        } catch (SQLException f) {
            System.out.println("delete errore"+f.getMessage()+Date.getCurrentDate());
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that you are not passing the data correctly: you are inlining the values ([which is a major security risk in itself](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection)) rather than passing them through query parameters.

Here is how you can fix it:

```
String sql = "insert into departments_log (DEPARTMENT_ID,entry_user,entry_date) values (?,?,?)";
PreparedStatement stm = getDBTransaction().createPreparedStatement(sql, 1);
stm.setInt(1, deptID);
stm.setString(2, entryUser.longValue());
stm.setDate(entryDate);
```

The above is only a skeleton of an implementation. You would need to add `null` checking of dates and `Numbers`, and make other modifications that improve robustness.

[Link to a tutorial on using parameteriszed prepared statements.](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/prepared.html)